# How do I create an MSI in VS 2008 to install a certificate into Trusted Publisher store on client machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, wix, windows-installer, certificate

What are the steps needed to create a VS 2008 MSI setup and deployment file to install a custom created certificate/key onto a client's machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The proper way is to use Wix3 instead of Visual Studio Deployment Project, Wix has the [Certificate element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_certificate.htm) which is pretty robust.
2. If you still want to use Visual Studio Deploy Project then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308554/install-certificates-in-to-the-windows-local-user-certificate-store-in-c/313876#313876) on how to install certificates using C#. You will need to warp this code inside an [Installer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) and [sequence it inside the deploy project](http://www.devcity.net/Articles/339/1/article.aspx).

Comment: WiX is a great solution for this.  Thank you!