# What is the best way to keep a console application running in the background?

Tags: c#

I am working on a console application that I want to run in the background of machines from the moment they boot to shutdown. Now I know that it would be optimum to create a Windows Service, but in this case I need to be able to intetact with certificate stores and I do not believe that a local service account certificate store will do.

I am looking at System.Timers for keeping the application running rather than bludgening in to death with an infinite while statement, is this a logical way to handle this or is there a better way in which to keep the application open? The application will be checking into a SQL database frequently to see if there is any work to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a windows service and impersonate the user to access the necessary certificate stores.  See this question: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308554/install-certificates-in-to-the-windows-local-user-certificate-store-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You can run Windows Services under any user with appropriate privileges. You are not required to run it under Local Service account.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use a tray icon to keep you application running, see [here for a sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/Creatingasystemtrayiconforyourapplication.htm).

Although, you can run the application as a windows service it requires additional installation overhead. Also = as far as I understand the OP - the application should close when the user logs out, this does not hold true for windows services. So you will have close it explicitly when this behaviour is required.

Comment: You beat me to it -- I'd consider a tray icon app.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I know that it would be optimum to create a Windows Service, but in this case I need to be able to intetact with certificate stores and I do not believe that a local service account certificate store will do.

In Windows XP:

Start->Settings->Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services

Right click on your service->Properties->Log On tab->This Account->Specify account to run as

It's something similar for Windows Vista and Windows 7 but I'm on an XP machine right now.

> I am looking at System.Timers for keeping the application running rather than bludgening in to death with an infinite while statement, is this a logical way to handle this or is there a better way in which to keep the application open?

A `System.Timers` is fine for periodically doing something. Again, you can implement this in a Windows service though.