# wcf ssl client on other pc

Tags: c#, wcf

I have built A webservice in WCF on a Server PC. I have made an https endpoint and configured some local certificates. Now on the network I am trying to create a C# console client to test the service. But i receive this error:
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException:
The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultE
xception: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authenti
cation failed.(and more)..

Here the code of the endpoint on which i want to connect to:

http://pastebin.com/GGe6YaTb

And this will be my client:

```
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WebDataServiceHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://anlocalip:9651/WebDataService" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WebDataServiceHttpBinding" contract="wcf1.IWebDataService"
            name="WebDataServiceHttpBinding">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I can't get out of this error, can someone help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to **install/import the certificate in the client's unit**.

> ### [How can I install a certificate into the local machine store programmatically using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566570/how-can-i-install-a-certificate-into-the-local-machine-store-programmatically-us)
> <sup>stackoverflow.com</sup>
>
> I have a certificate generated via MakeCert. I want to use this certificate for WCF message security using PeerTrust. How can I programmatically install the certificate into the "trusted people" local machine certificate store using c# or .NET?

> ### [Install certificates in to the Windows Local user certificate store in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308554/install-certificates-in-to-the-windows-local-user-certificate-store-in-c-sharp)
> <sup>stackoverflow.com</sup>
>
> I'm writing a windows service that needs several certificates in the certificate store in order to connect to a third party web service...

Or to **secure the service with a certificate**.

> ### [How to: Secure a Service with an X.509 Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788968.aspx)
> <sup>msdn.microsoft.com</sup>
>
> Securing a service with an X.509 certificate is a basic technique that most bindings in Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) use. This topic walks through the steps of configuring a self-hosted service with an X.509 certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting impersonation level before opening your proxy:

```
serviceProxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
serviceProxy.Open();
```

Comment: doesnt work, on the client config i have changed <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"> to <security mode="Transport"> and then i get this error..:Unhandled Exception:System.ServiceModel.FaultException : The message could not be processed. This is most likely the action 'http://mynamespace/Login  is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or
because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token
would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from... etc.

Comment: According to documentation, HttpClientCredentialType is ignored in TransportWithMessageCredential mode. Try to have something simpler working first, like Transport security with ClientCredentialType="Basic"

Comment: wcf the username is not provided. specify username in clientcredentials

Comment: Of course you have to provide user and pass via `serviceProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName` before opening proxy and implement custom `UserNamePasswordValidator` in your service behavior.

Comment: Do you insist on using Windows credential type? Otherwise I can show you how to authenticate using User/Pass.

Comment: Maciej how do i do that i only have the xml config files of the wcf service

Comment: @user1350954 You have to be able to change your code to solve this. Configuration alone is not enough.